# Removing only part of character line in txt file - chr string

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, genetics, vcf-variant-call-format

I would like to remove strings "chr" in a following txt file, using bash:

```
    FO538757.1      chr1:183937
    AL669831.3      chr1:601436
    AL669831.3      chr1:601667
    AL669831.3      chr1:609395
    AL669831.3      chr1:609407
    AL669831.3      chr1:611317
```

So that end file looks like:

```
FO538757.1      1:183937
AL669831.3     1:601436
AL669831.3     1:601667
AL669831.3     1:609395
AL669831.3     1:609407
AL669831.3     1:611317
```

2. I checked previous threads and tried:

   ```
   sed 's/^chr//' 
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {gsub(/chr1/,"1",$2)}2'
   ```
3. none of them worked. Is here any better option than awk?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you **really** have a bunch of blanks at the start of each line that you want to also remove? You're getting answers assuming that you do so if not then please [edit] your question to fix your example.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect all you really need is:

```
sed 's/chr//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that quite easily with `sed` and two expressions, (1) the first to remove `chr` and the second to remove leading whitespace, e.g.

```
sed -e 's/chr//' -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'  file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in the file named `file`, you would have

```
$ sed -e 's/chr//' -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*//'  file
FO538757.1      1:183937
AL669831.3      1:601436
AL669831.3      1:601667
AL669831.3      1:609395
AL669831.3      1:609407
AL669831.3      1:611317
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Simple explanation would be: substituting starting chr with NULL in 2nd field and printing the line then, which will cause reconstruct of current line and initial spaces will be removed too from line.

```
awk '{sub(/^chr/,"",$2)} 1' Input_file
```

In case your Input_file is tab delimited and having tabs in starting of file then try following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {sub(/^chr/,"",$3);sub(/^\t+/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `bash` shell with [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `mapfile` aka `readarray`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

mapfile -t array < file.txt

array=("${array[@]##+([[:space:]])}")

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]/chr}"
```

---

Inside the script `extglob` must be enable but in the command line it might be enabled already, so in-one-line

```
mapfile -t array < file.txt; array=("${array[@]##+([[:space:]])}"); printf '%s\n' "${array[@]/chr}"
```

It will be very slow for large set of data/files, jfyi